# Virtual path exception in asp.Net

Tags: asp.net

I have to save files to a physical folder. But i got the following exception. "The path is not a virtual path" How can i change a physical path to a virtual path. How can i solve this problem

```
Grades grade = new Grades(); 
grade.Exam = Exams.Search(ddlExam.SelectedValue); 
grade.Person = Person.GetStudent(ddlStudent.SelectedValue); 
try{ 
     if (afuPaper.HasFile) 
     { 
          string strPath = Server.MapPath(grade.Exam.FileUrl) + ddlExam.SelectedValue + 
               grade.Person.TcNo + Path.GetFileName(afuPaper.FileName);
          afuPaper.SaveAs(strPath); grade.GradeJpeg = strPath; 
     }
}
```

Comment: Grades grade = new Grades();
            grade.Exam = Exams.Search(ddlExam.SelectedValue);
            grade.Person = Person.GetStudent(ddlStudent.SelectedValue);
           


            try
            {
                
                if (afuPaper.HasFile)
                {
                    
                    string strPath = Server.MapPath(grade.Exam.FileUrl) + ddlExam.SelectedValue + grade.Person.TcNo + Path.GetFileName(afuPaper.FileName);
                    afuPaper.SaveAs(strPath);
                    grade.GradeJpeg = strPath;
                    
                }

Answer (score 0):

Grades grade = new Grades();
            grade.Exam = Exams.Search(ddlExam.SelectedValue);
            grade.Person = Person.GetStudent(ddlStudent.SelectedValue);

```
        try
        {

            if (afuPaper.HasFile)
            {

                string strPath = Server.MapPath(grade.Exam.FileUrl) + ddlExam.SelectedValue + grade.Person.TcNo + Path.GetFileName(afuPaper.FileName);
                afuPaper.SaveAs(strPath);
                grade.GradeJpeg = strPath;

            }
```

Comment: grade.Exam.FileUrl is a pyhsical path like C:\\File\\Paper1

Answer (score 0):

grade.Exam.FileUrl is a pyhsical path like C:\File\Paper1

Answer (score 0):

Server.MapPath expects a virtual path and converts it to a physical path.

Assuming you require a physical path for SaveAs, then you can simply remove that call.

The MapPath method is used to convert a virtual path, such as "~/Location/File.aspx" to a physical path such as "C:\inetput\wwwroot\MyApplication1\Location\File.aspx"

EDIT: Modified code

```
    try
    {
        if (afuPaper.HasFile)
        {
            string strPath = Path.Combine(grade.Exam.FileUrl, ddlExam.SelectedValue + grade.Person.TcNo + Path.GetFileName(afuPaper.FileName));
            afuPaper.SaveAs(strPath);
            grade.GradeJpeg = strPath;

        }
```

Note that I also included a call to Path.Combine, which is the method of choice for combining a folder and file name (It will automatically add a \ if needed between FileUrl and whatever)